# Solving nonlinear inequality that involves norm2 operator

Tags: inequalities, matrix-equations

I have an equation of the form 
$$ \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert} \norm{\mathbf{Z} \left[ \sum_{n = 0}^{N - 1} (-1)^n \psi^n \mathbf{C}^n \right] \mathbf{q}  }^2 \leq |p|^2, $$ where $\mathbf{C}$ is a $L \times L$ ($L = 16$) square matrix (known), $\mathbf{q}$ is a $L \times 1$ vector (known), $\mathbf Z$ is a $M \times L$ matrix (known), $p$ is a complex number (known), and $N$ is a given integer number (known).

The unknown is the scalar $\psi$ that must be greater than 0.

I have tried to solve this by expanding the expression in bracket, but I cannot make any assumption on the value of $\psi$.

Could you please help me solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: the question is not clear; what about $\psi=0$?

Comment: Thank you, Suvrit. You're right. $\psi > 0$ is a scalar and must be greater than 0.

Comment: It is not clear what is it that you are trying to solve. What you have written is an inequality, not an equation. In particular, since $C, q, Z, p$ are all fixed, I don't see why making $\psi \to 0$ will not solve the inequality. I must be missing something...

Comment: I am trying to find the maximum value of $0 <\psi < 1$ that solves the inequality. Sorry for the confusion.